# Left-to-right animation on Android with react-native-navigation when pushing new screen to stack

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-navigation

On Android with `react-native-navigation`, when pushing a new screen to the stack, I’d like the transition animation to be from left-to-right (or vice-versa, for RTL layout)
In iOS it‘s the default, where as on Android – it seems to be shown with cross-dissolve animation. how can I achieve the horizontal animation as in iOS?

Answer (score 8):

Here is an example stack navigator for you:

```js
import { createStackNavigator, CardStyleInterpolators } from "@react-navigation/stack";

class CompaniesIndex extends React.Component<
  ICompaniesIndexProps,
  ICompaniesIndexState
  > {
  render() {
    return (
      <CompanyStack.Navigator
        mode="modal"
        screenOptions={{
          cardStyleInterpolator: CardStyleInterpolators.forHorizontalIOS
        }}
        initialRouteName="AllCompanies">
        <CompanyStack.Screen
          options={{
            title: "Firma Listesi",
            header: (props) => <Header {...props} />,
          }}
          name="AllCompanies"
          component={CompaniesAll}
        />
        <CompanyStack.Screen
          options={{
            title: "Yeni Firma",
            header: (props) => <Header {...props} />,
          }}
          name="NewCompany"
          component={CompanyNew}
        />
        <CompanyStack.Screen
          options={{
            title: "Firma Detayı",
            header: (props) => <Header {...props} />,
          }}
          name="CompanyDetails"
          component={CompanyDetails}
        />
      </CompanyStack.Navigator>
    );
  }
}
```

You can achieve that with adding `screenOptions={{cardStyleInterpolator: CardStyleInterpolators.forHorizontalIOS}}` in your stack navigator.

Comment: thank you! But I actually meant `react-native-navigation`, not `react-navigation`...
But thank you again!

Comment: Thank you!, but with this solution a have a litle bounce when I used goBack() so I ended up using `{TransitionPresets } from '@react-navigation/stack';` and in my navigator `<Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{ ...TransitionPresets.SlideFromRightIOS }}>`

Answer (score 5):

For `react-navigation@6.0.1`, use  `animation: "slide_from_right"` in screenOptions.

```
 <Stack.Navigator
  screenOptions={{
    headerShown: false,
    animation: "slide_from_right",
  }}
```

Comment: thank you! But I actually meant `react-native-navigation`, not r`eact-navigation`... But thank you again!

Comment: this worked for ```react-native-navigation```

Answer (score -1):

if you use native-stack ([@react-navigation/native-stack](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/native-stack-navigator/) or [react-native-screens/native-stack](https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-screens)), just input 'stackAnimation' option in screenOptions of your Navigator!

```
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from 'react-native-screens/native-stack';

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();
<Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{ headerShown: false, stackAnimation: 'slide_from_right' }}>
  <Stack.Screen name="First" component={FirstScreen} />
  <Stack.Screen name="Second" component={SecondScreen} />
</Stack.Navigator>
```

Comment: Thank you! But I’m using react-native-navigation, not react-navigation…